# Updating Kernel on a Redhat Azure VM is failing

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, azure

I am trying to run yum update on my Azure Redhat VM : yum update -y
And I am getting this error :

```
Error: Package: containerd.io-1.2.6-3.3.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce)
           Requires: container-selinux >= 2:2.74
           Installed: 2:container-selinux-2.9-4.el7.noarch (installed)
               container-selinux = 2:2.9-4.el7
Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.1-3.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce)
           Requires: container-selinux >= 2:2.74
           Installed: 2:container-selinux-2.9-4.el7.noarch (installed)
               container-selinux = 2:2.9-4.el7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this command to re-install stable docker-ce and containerd.io

```
sudo yum install docker-ce-stable docker-ce-cli containerd.io-stable
```

This should solve the error